# make specific data points in scatter plot seaborn more visible

Tags: pandas, seaborn, scatter-plot

i am struggling here, i really need help to make those NOK points in the scatter plot more visible

i have a dataset with two output variables `['OK','NOK']`,the size of the two is unequal

**size of the OK is 60 thousand and size of NOK is 160**

this is what i get when i plot the data:
[image]

this is my code:

```
for i in X.columns:
plt.figure()
sns.scatterplot(data=df,x='Time',y=i,hue='Desc Level 2')
```

i would really appreciate your help

**Note: since x-axis is time axis, sns.Implot did not work since it only accepts float or string arguments**

Comment: Plot the rare class second so it's on top?

Comment: @mwaskom i didn't understand what you mean, could you please explain more?

Comment: `ax = sns.scatterplot(data=df[df['Desc Level 2']=='OK'],x='Time',y=i,label='OK')` followed by `sns.scatterplot(data=df[df['Desc Level 2']=='NOK'],x='Time',y=i,label='NOK', ax=ax)`

Comment: @JohanC your code works, thanks a lot, can you please explain more about your solution or a reference i can read